# Using interactions with time variable in fixed effects modelling (PLM package R)

Tags: r, econometrics, fixed-effects-model, plm

I'm trying to run some fixed effects models for housing stress using the PLM package in R. Based on the existing examples/documentation time variables are often used as part of the index to identify the individual/time period for each observation, for example:

```
Model1 <- plm(Stress ~ V1 + V2, data = Data1, model = "fixed",
      index = c("time", "household"))
```

I would also like to look at the interaction between one of my variables and time. In that case, would I be right to use something like:

```
Model2 <- plm(Stress ~ V1*time + V2, data = Data1, model = "fixed",
      index = c("household"))
```

Packages like lme4 can run mixed effects models with time interactions, so intuitively PLM should allow this as they do similar things (although using a different type of estimation). I'm mostly concerned about whether running Model2 would violate fundamental rules about how models should be run in this package (not too familiar with econometrics/PLM).

Comment: I was also wondering about that. I wonder we could simply "pre-create" the interaction as a new variable and use it in plm(), as "V1_t <-  V1*time"